# Aligning Images in Tables and Lists

Tags: html, images, table

I am trying to layout a list vertically that has a checkbox, image and description....

see here for an example...

http://www.sk8loc8.com/deposit/list.jpg

As you can see the images look a bit too high and i would like them to 'sink' a little to line up with the text and checkbox.

i put them in a table to get around the issue, but it acts just the same as an unordered list and the image sits higher.

i tried using valign=top for the text and checkbox but this doesnt seem to work, neither does adding a bottom-margin to the text, or adding a top-margin to the image.

does anyone have any advice?

here is the markup...

```
<table id="mapLegend" class="mapLegendTable" border="1" cellpadding="5px">
        <tr title="A skatepark we know exists">
            <td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><img src="assets/images/gIconRedDot.png" alt="Skatepark" /></td>
            <td valign="top">Park</td>
        </tr>
         <tr title="A skatepark we strongly recommend">
            <td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><img src="assets/images/gIconYellowStar.png" alt="Recommended Skatepark" /></td>
            <td valign="top">Recommended Park</td>
        </tr>
         <tr title="A Skater Owned Shop">
            <td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><img src="assets/images/gIconSkateshop.png" alt="Skate Shop" /></td>
            <td valign="top">Skate Shop</td>
        </tr>
         <tr title="A skatepark we do not know anything about. It MAY exist but we do not know for sure">
            <td valign="top"><input type="checkbox" /></td>
            <td><img src="assets/images/gIconUnconfirmedSpot.png" alt="Unconfirmed Skatepark" /></td>
            <td valign="top">Unconfirmed Park</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

and the old code, as an unordered list...

```
<ul id="mapLegend">
                <li id="parkIcon" title="A skatepark we know exists">
                    <img src="assets/images/gIconRedDot.png" alt="Skatepark" /><span>Park</span></li>
                <li id="recommendedParkIcon" title="A skatepark we recommend">
                    <img src="assets/images/gIconYellowStar.png" alt="Skatepark" />Recommended Park</li>
                <li id="shopIcon" title="A Skater Owned Shop">
                    <img src="assets/images/gIconSkateshop.png" alt="Skatepark" />Skate Shop</li>
                <li id="unconfirmedParkIcon" title="A skatepark we do not know anything about. It MAY exist but we do not know for sure">
                    <img src="assets/images/gIconUnconfirmedSpot.png" alt="Skatepark" />Unconfirmed
                    Park</li>
            </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list will do. You need to apply the 'vertical-align:top' style to the images. I usually use 'middle' for this which looks a little better for one-liners.

This can be done in your image direction, as in:

```
<img src="assets/images/gIconRedDot.png" alt="Skatepark" style="vertical-align:top"/>
```

Or by CSS:

```
#mapLegend li img {
vertical-align:top;
}
```